# Do static variables and methods belong to java.lang.Class object of that class?

Tags: java, class, oop, static

I have read lot of questions on this topic and many of them say the static content (`static methods` and `variables`) belongs to `java.lang.Class` object (also known as class level object which lives in Permanent Generation) and the reasons behind this are

1. In Java specification, we can found this "static content belongs to some internal structure of the class which is common to all objects and exist outside of the objects".

As mentioned in §8.3.1.1 of Java Language Specification

> If a field is declared static, there exists exactly one incarnation of
>   the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class
>   may eventually be created. A static field, sometimes called a class
>   variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized (§12.4).

2. `java.lang.Class` object of a class represents the internal structure of the class, there exists exactly one incarnation of it and it is common to all objects.
3. `java.lang.Class` object gets created in Perm Gen when the class is loaded and initialized.
4. `java.lang.Class` is known as the class level object and static variables are called class variable because static variables lie as the state of the class level object.
5. While synchronizing a static method we need to get the lock on the class level object which is again `java.lang.Class` instance.

As mentioned in §8.4.3.6 says:

> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class
>   object for the method's class is used.

From above points, we can conclude that static content belongs to `java.lang.Class` instance but why is it not written clearly anywhere in any specification?

And also if `class A { static int b; }` why is `b` is not accessible via `A.class.b`?

So how would you prove that the static variables and methods belong to the `Class` object?

And if the static content doesn't belong to the Class object, then where exactly does it belong? and why do lots of answers, blogs and tutorials mention it?

Comment: It's more that they only ever have a single instance, they don't "belong" to the class as much as they don't belong to any one object

Answer (score 0):

[§8.3.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1) of Java Language Specification states the following:

> If a field is declared `static`, there exists exactly one incarnation of the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class may eventually be created. A `static` field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized (§12.4).

And [§8.4.3.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1) says:

> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the `Class` object for the method's class is used.

Neither of them specifies an object, that should contain `static` fields.

As you mentioned:

> static content belongs to some internal structure the class which is common to all objects and exist **outside of the objects**".

This includes instances of the `Class`. These instances describes parts of the internal structures, but does not contains them.

So, unfortunately, the statement you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: This why I have asked this question, there is no proof of it in any specification (JVMS, JLS) but it looks like static content belongs to the Class level object. For example, if the static content does not belong to class level object then why do we need to take a lock on Class object to make the static method synchronized?

Comment: and as you have quoted from JLS "A static field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized (§12.4).", A class will be initialized means the class level object of java.lang.Class<YourClass> get created.

Comment: No, they are not. The reason for usage of `Class` object for `synchronization` of static method, is just a convenient agreement. Any other object that have exactly one instance for each loaded class will fit. Fortunately, the JVM already have this kind of objects -- the `Class` objects.

Comment: There are two different stages in the life of the class: 1) class loading 2) class initialization. The `Class` instance is created on the first stage, while static fields are initialized on the second.

Comment: Surely object will get created first (during class loading phase) and static variable initialization will be done later (during the initialization phase) but initialization will be done with the object which gets created during class loading which is Class object.

Comment: `Class` objects contain only (meta)information about class structure, not the values of methods itself.

Comment: static methods can be synchronized . There is only one copy of the static data you're trying to protect, so you only need one lock per class to synchronize static methods—a lock for the whole class. There is such a lock; every class loaded in Java has a corresponding instance of java.lang.Class representing that class. It's that java.lang.Class instance whose lock is used to protect the static methods of the class (if they're synchronized ).

Comment: That's true. But this nohow implies that `Class` objects contains class fields or methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127437/discussion-between-naresh-joshi-and-kgeorgiy).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking seemingly disparate questions as one question. This is perhaps the main source of your confusion. Also, while dealing with language specifications, we need to be precise with respect to names so that the confusion is minimized.

*Static Content* is a term used in website organization. You seem to imply static fields and methods (together called *static members*) of Java classes when you refer to *static content*. Let's just use the term *static members* to be clear.

> From above points, we can conclude that static content belongs to `java.lang.Class` instance but why is it not written clearly anywhere in any specification?

[§15.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11) tries to specify that static members are accessed through a *PrimaryName* and an *identifier* using the expression `Primary . Identifier`.

In the simplest of cases, the spec says: **The type of the Primary must be a reference type T, or a compile-time error occurs**. This means that the static members are to be accessed through the *name* of the type that defines the members.

> And also if `class A { static int b; }` why is b is not accessible via A.class.b?

For the same reason as above, that `A.class` is not the reference *type* that *defines* the static field `b`. The type is `A` and hence `b` is accessible only as `A.b`.

And as Java programmers, we do thank Java's designers that we can access static members like `A`'s `b` simply as `A.b`, don't we?

A somewhat longer explanation has to deal with Java's reflective capabilities, in particular, the class `java.lang.Class`. **This is the only class in Java whose instances are classes**. Yes, instances of `java.lang.Class` are classes. Thus, `java.lang.String` is an *instance* of `java.lang.Class` just like a string `String s = "foo";` is an *instance* of the class `java.lang.String`. The program:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "foo";
    System.out.println(String.class instanceof Class);  // statically
    System.out.println(Class.class.isInstance(String.class)); // dynamically
    System.out.println(s instanceof String); // statically
    System.out.println(String.class.isInstance(s)); // dynamically
  }
}
```

prints:

```
true
true
true
true
```

One question may linger and that is what exactly is `A.class`? The [spec defines it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) as *Class Literal*:

**A class literal evaluates to the Class object for the named type (or for void) as defined by the defining class loader (§12.2) of the class of the current instance.**

So, any methods that could be invoked on say `String.class` (remember, `String.class` is the *receiver* here) are the methods defined on *its class which is the class `java.lang.Class`*. Thus, you can do `String.class.isInstance(str)` just the same way that you can call `str.length()` where `str` is an instance of `String` (and `length()` is the so-called instance method defined on the `String` class; the instance method and class method distinction is irrelevant here).

> So how would you prove that the static variables and methods belong to the Class object?

From 1) above, i.e. from the fact that they are only accessible via the name of the type (i.e. `class` or `interface`) the declares them. There is a small wrinkle here. A static member is also accessible through the instances of the type defining them and following example may surprise you. What does this program do:

```
public class Main {
  static int foo = 22;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Main m = null;
      System.out.println(m.foo); // ** Don't Do This **
  }
}
```

No, it does not throw `NullPointerException`. The access to static members is allowed (although discouraged) through *instances of the class that defines them*. And since `javac` understands the Java Language Spec like no one else, it does the thing that spec wants it to.

But note that if you used the defining type or an instance of that type, it would fetch the exact same value of the static fields and will call the exact same static method at runtime. This is a good enough proof to satisfy ourselves that the static members indeed are a characteristic of the type (or class) that defines them.

Comment: Kedar thanks for your answer, I do know that we can access static members from an instance and I am aware of other things you have mentioned i.e. String.class is actually an object of java.lang.Class<String> but all of above explanation does not give me any clue on why static members do not belong to class level object